# laravel validation, what does it return if validation passes?

Tags: database, validation, laravel, conditional-statements, store

There something I don't understand.
When passing input to the controller I have it validate with laravel, example:

```
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'post_id' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'

        ]);
```

now the point is, do I have to make a condition before inserting in the DB? and if so how? I mean (pseudo code)

```
if data is validated { store in DB }
```

or will `validate` get ahold of everything and simply stop if erros are found?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
// define rules
  $rules = array(
    'user_id' => 'required',
    'post_id' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required'
   );

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails())
{
  // something
  // return Redirect::back()
  //        ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
  //        ->withInput();
}
else
{
  // something
  $data->save(); // save your data 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If validation fails the errors are pushed into session and the user will be redirected to the previus location.

If the validation goes well, the code after  `$this->validate(...)` will be executed.

Comment: Ok and what if you are return a json for a script?